# Composer user on Ubuntu

Tags: composer-php, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-5.4

trying `composer update` throw this exception on laravel :

> [RuntimeException]
>   Could not delete
>   /home/sherkat2017/ftp/www/vendor/symfony/yaml/Dumper.php:

even running `chmod 775 -R vendor` and `chown sher:www-data -R vendor` did not solve issue:

```
drwxrwxr-x  8 sher www-data        4096 Apr 13 18:25 storage
```

I think composer run as a user different from `www-data` .

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

- Delete your /vendor folder
- Delete composer.lock
- Run composer install

and Run these commands while re-install

- composer install --no-dev --no-scripts
- composer install --no-dev -o
- composer install

Comment: when i run `composer install` get `/home/sher/ftp/www/vendor does not exist and could not be created.`

Comment: i can set permission `777` for www folder temporary but i'm looking for a consistant way